# Multiple fragments inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, fragment, android-linearlayout

Trying to place two fragments inside a LinearLayout with the following XML -

**MainActivity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.frag.myfragmentapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainTV"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:name="com.frag.myfragmentapplication.fragTwo"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment2" />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:name="com.frag.myfragmentapplication.fragOne"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity code**:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

While in Design mode it looks okay but when I run this testing app I get the following error -

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.frag.myfragmentapplication/com.frag.myfragmentapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment*

Not sure what is wrong with the code, help will be appreciated.

Comment: put weightsum =2 for linear layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to debug your code I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: berkaykoksal.com.test.testapp.MainActivity@308e8a6 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Now I removed one of the fragments and tried it with one which still gave the same error. That means the problem you have has nothing to do with multiple fragments. The problem is that you created your fragment.java files but did not delete *unused* functions. The main one causing problem here is the OnFragmentInterractionListener being not implemented properly. But well you do not need it do you? Soooo

If you edit your java classes like this to only have OnCreateView function:

```
package *****;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class fragTwo extends Fragment {

    public fragTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_two, container, false);
    }

}
```

And

```
package *****;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class fragOne extends Fragment {

    public fragOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

You will notice the problem will be fixed. It did work on me and if you have any further questions I can help out.

*And always remember to give ID values to your fragments in XML file.*

```
android:id="@+id/fragmentcontentarea1"
android:id="@+id/fragmentcontentarea2"
```

Good Luck!

Comment: My fragment classes include **only** OnCreateView methods, I do not have any other functions there. If I remove the LinearLayout surrounding the fragmens and set **android:layout_width="match_parent"** it works fine.

Comment: After adding id's to the fragmen tags it works like a charm. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your fragment has a different name than the one you define in the layout. Can you confirm that you have a file

```
com.frag.myfragmentapplication.fragTwo.java
```

Note that capitalization is important.

Comment: I do have these classes. If I remove the LinearLayout than it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```